# Java WorldWind : translate whole globe

Tags: java, opengl, translate-animation, worldwind

I am doing extensive use of Java WorldWind and have difficulties to implement some more feature with 3d rendering. At first, I had huge difficulties with zoom and [BasicOrbitView](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/2.0/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/view/orbit/BasicOrbitView.html), as zoom actually changes point of view elevation, which changes the horizon and hence is not a zoom. I solved that using [FOV parameter](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/2.0/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/view/BasicView.html#fieldOfView). Decreasing this parameter performs a real zoom, as visualized object is only modified by an homothetic transformation. I explain that to let know the level of details I hide behind words such as "zoom" or "translate".

Now I have a second issue with "translate": I want to translate the whole earth along screen X and Y axis without horizon change or whatever. Objective is to combine both FOV change with translation change to zoom on some earth edges.

Zooming on some earth edge is possible using roll and pitch, at the condition that the edge is located up on your screen, which forbids to have pole north up, zooming at earth edge on equator for example (if not clear I will provide illustrations). So this attempt was unsuccessful. I worked a lot on BasicOrbitView.setOrientation method unsuccessfully.

I also tried to modify the OpenGL view matrices behind the View, trying to multiply it with a 4x4 matrix describing a translation, unsuccessfully (execution crashes during worldwind subroutines).

Have you an idea on how to implement that translation in worldwind ?